# Bot is developed using azure bot framework and deployed in teams channel. It is working fine in teams desktop/web app but not in mobile andriod app

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Bot is working fine in team desktop app but not in mobile android app. It is not responding at all after showing herocard.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the error that you are facing?

Comment: bot is created and delployed in teams channel. it is working fine in teams desktop app, all the cards are displayed .action type is working . But the same bot is not working in teams andriod app(from phone). the cards are not displaying , not responding